# Can an email be modified after/during a throttled send?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, send-throttling

Case: Have to send an email to a large audience. It is going at 1500 per hour for 14 hours a day. After the first 3 hours someone tell me they have made an error and a line has to be removed.
I have paused the send.

Question: If I modify the template at this stage, will the rest of the send use the unmodified or the modified template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_pause_resume_send_in_tracking.htm&type=5), you can't edit the content while the send is paused (it's packaged at the original point of send and cannot be modified after).

One option for you would be to pause, then cancel the send. You can then add everyone already sent the email to a list, which you can use as a suppression when you recreate the send (with updated creative), so you're only sending to those who have not yet received it.

Comment: thank you @Antonio. I couldn't find this. That is what I feared.